# Graphics trouble after resuming from hibernate or suspend

Tags: suspend, hibernate, resume

I have a Dell Inspiron 2650 (with NVidia graphics, using nouveau drivers) that I'm using to try out Ubuntu. It's all great, except that Hibernate and Suspend aren't usable.

Yes, I know that questions about power-save issues are rampant in the Linux support universe, but it seems that every time I find a solution it's for a very specific hardware combination and doesn't apply to me. So anyway, here goes.

When I resume from either power-saving mode, I'll get graphics problems anywhere on the range from a few scattered random-colored pixels that won't change; all the way to full-screen patterns that don't change as I move the mouse, hit keys on the keyboard, or even bring up the shutdown dialog using the power button.

Those full-screen issues (which may involve stripes with random pixels, partial black screen, or both) always end in me forcing the machine to shut down by holding the power button.

I haven't done much testing yet to determine what severity level is most commonly associated with each mode, but I do avoid using either power-save option because of these issues.

<del>I'll add info on my hardware as I can gather it (no home internet connection, and this laptop is tethered to my desk by a dead battery and casing degradation).</del> Please feel free to request something specific in the question comments.

#### Hardware Info

See [this hardinfo report](http://bits.technobabbl.es/hardinfo_report.html) for my system's hardware configuration. (No, my username is not "myuser"; I sanitized hardinfo's output before publishing it.)

#### Screenshots

These screenshots are from a relatively mild occurrence, which happened after the second hibernation I took that session. The first one worked great, though I used the wireless card and Firefox heavily between the two hibernation attempts.

[image]

Take a look at what happened when I opened my home directory in Nautilus and scrolled it:

[image]

See below for the situations I've tested so far. The real trouble comes when the machine resumes to an unusable state; in such cases I can't even unlock the screen or properly reboot, much less take a screenshot. I have a hunch that putting a CD in the drive will cause such major failures, and I will try that at some point; [see related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17260/various-issues-linked-to-my-cd-drive-when-it-has-a-disc-in-it).

### Situations Tested

#### Maverick (10.10)

Suspend

- Seems to suspend nicely with nothing running
- Seems to suspend nicely with flash drive plugged in
- On resume from suspend with no flash drive, Terminal and gedit running: Funky graphics on top of log output, then blank screen with pixelated cursor; no response to power button (normally will shutdown 60 seconds later)

Hibernate

- Seems to hibernate nicely with nothing running
- Seems to hibernate nicely with a few apps (Terminal, Mouse preferences) running
- Seems to not hibernate when flash drive plugged in
- Seems to not hibernate when System Monitor is running
- Have encountered failed hibernation (after several hours and one successful hibernate/thaw cycle) with no external media connected and no programs running except normal background stuff

#### Natty LiveCD (11.04_2010-12-22)

When I tested it, Natty wouldn't stay logged in. It played part of the login sound and then `[ OK ]` appeared in the top right corner (white-on-black terminal text) for a few seconds. Then it kicked me back to the Unlock screen. It did that four times before I gave up and just tested suspend from the Unlock screen.

Suspend

- Resumed to vertical gray and black lines 2px (?) wide, then shifted to vertical "jail bars" of black over a black screen with above-described random pixels and mouse pointer. No apparent response to input from mouse (clicking randomly). Keyboard and touchpad unrecognized.

Comment: use [hardinfo](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/hardinfo) to get the system information. Also can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Can you confirm that you have Nvidia graphics and you are using nouveau graphics drivers.  If so does a natty liveCD work for you?

Comment: I have added the graphics info to the question. I'll download and test a Natty daily build in the next few days and come back with the results of that. Can I really test hibernate/suspend with a LiveCD?

Comment: Results of suspend test with Natty (2010-12-22) added

Comment: Do you have at least as much swap as you have physical memory?

Comment: Good call, but that wouldn't affect suspend/resume, only hibernation.

Comment: For the record, I do.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with graphics on my Asrock 100HT (core i3) using 10.10 after suspend. How to solve it ?

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty clearly a bug and not something that should have to be worked around or which could be fixed through user action. The best thing to do in these cases is to open a bug in launchpad so that Ubuntu developers can see it and track it.

For suspend/resume or hibernate problems, it's best to open the bug against the linux kernel. You can do that from a shell by typing:

```
ubuntu-bug linux
```

Answer (score 0):

When I upgraded from 10.10 -> 11.04, I had to re-install ACPI.

Here's a debugging guide:  [https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingACPI](http://ittyb.it/u5c895d84)

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 20.04 user here. My WIFI tends to fail after resuming from hibernate and enabling hybrid graphics would block hibernation. Plus, regular boot would throw a bunch of ACPI errors before the Login screen appears.

From [this hibernation setup guide](https://blog.ivansmirnov.name/how-to-set-up-hibernate-on-ubuntu-20-04/), I noticed the issue was while I specified the swap file to store the hibernation image in fstab, I did not specify the swap file to *resume* from under [initramfs](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Initramfs).

I suspect you already specified where to store the hibernation image in fstab? Then the next steps are to:

1. Add the same swap partition UUID to `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` with:

```
# write the resume UUID (make sure to replace this with your UUID)
echo RESUME=UUID=your-swap-partition-uuid   | sudo tee /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
```

2. Recreate initramfs with `sudo update-initramfs -c -k all`